# Aircraft fuel rate differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Aircraft have worse performance when they are more loaded of fuel. This dynamics can be represented by the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\phi}=\rho-\lambda\phi\mathrm{,}
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is the amount of fuel, $\rho$ is a constant value corresponding to the fuel rate when $\phi\rightarrow 0 $, and $\lambda$ is another constant. This means that the rate of fuel consumption is proportional to the opposite of the sum of a constant fuel rate, due to the invariant vehicle physics, with a term proportional to the current amount of fuel. In more informal words, the amount of fuel burnt per second is higher when there is more fuel to be carried.

A solution for equation above can be obtained by Laplace:
\begin{equation}
\phi(t)=\left(\phi(0)-\frac{\rho}{\lambda}\right)e^{-\lambda t}+\frac{\rho}{\lambda}\mathrm{.}
\end{equation}
However, I am intersted in knowing if it is possible to deduce this solution by other method. For example, if $\rho=0$, one can solve by integration:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-\lambda\phi\iff\frac{d\phi}{\phi} = -\lambda dt \implies \log\phi(t)=-\lambda t + K\implies \phi(t)=e^K e^{-\lambda t}
\end{equation}
So, is it possible to solve the first differential equation by integration or some "elementary" method?

Comment: In aeronautical engineering, this formulation is related to the Breguet equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution when $\rho=0$ is the exponential you obtained. 
Now, you can easily see that $\phi=\frac{\rho}{\lambda}$ is a particular (constant) solution. Then you add both solution and find your $K$ constant by taking the value $t=0$

Answer (score 1):

A usual technique is to solve the homogeneous equation (without the constant term) as you have done to get a general solution, then add that to any particular solution of the whole equation.  In your case, maybe you can see by inspection that $\phi=\frac \rho \lambda, \dot \phi =0$ is a solution.  In that case your total solution is $\phi(t)=\frac \rho \lambda + e^Ke^{-\lambda t}$ and you need to evaluate $K$ from the initial conditions.